# Does the angle of refraction depend on an observer?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, observers

According to Fermat's principle, light should take the least time between two points. Therefore, is it correct to say that the angle of refraction is solely dependent on the difference between speed of light in two mediums? Surely the the position of the observer is a key factor too, given the findings of the double-slit experiment that show a photon is only actualised on measurement/observation. Does this not imply the necessity of an observer for the existence of an angle of refraction?

Comment: Your answer is unclear because Fermat's principle states that the path followed by light is *stationary*, not minimal. If you want to restrict the problem to the situation where it's actually minimal, you should provide additional details.

Comment: I agree my question could have been clearer. I've made an edit to it now, so hopefully that clarifies things better.

Answer (score 0):

It's about where the light source is, no matter where you observe this from, if the light source is perpendicular to the water surface then light would refract the same way (there is refraction angle 0 and speed would reduce). So no, refraction is not observer dependent.